# phpMyAdmin can't connect to the MySQL server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, mamp

I am using MAMP.

It seems that when I tried making some changes with the passwords, I messed it up and now I can't access anything on phpMyAdmin.

I've tried to reinstall MAMP, but all I get is still the same error.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image]

UPDATE: Even in terminal I get the same error

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Please post textual error messages as text, not as illegible screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

check your configuration file in MAMP, the password isn't defined

The reinstallation doesnt rewrite conf files

Comment: I checked the conf file, and I thought that the password is set to root, since it says: 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';

Was I wrong?

Comment: Since the problem also occurs from the command-line client, this seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting your root password via the console. [Instructions can be found here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

The instructions cover Windows and *Nix.

The reason why when you re-installed MAMP/WAMP/LAMP/MySQL etc and it doesn't remove the password is because it saves the config files, and when you remove MySQL it doesn't delete the config files relating to the passwords. 
I've had this issue on Windows and Linux - But I can see it affects Mac's too.

Edit: I am assuming you have console access, because you mention MAMP - If you don't, try your host' control panel, it will have an option for Mysql there.